# Python polars: can I use `to_datetime()` on multiple columns in parallel?

Tags: python, python-polars

I want to turn all columns ending with `'_at'` into `datetime`s. Can I somehow combine these two ideas so the operation is efficient?

Selecting multiple columns:

```py
import polars.selectors as cs

dt_cols = df.select(cs.ends_with('_at'))
```

Converting a single column to a datetime:

```py
df.with_columns(pl.col('thing_1_updated_at').str.to_datetime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%.3f%:z"))
```

But after some searching and fiddling I can't get the combination of them to work:

```py
import polars.selectors as cs

df.with_columns(cs.ends_with('_at').str.to_datetime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%.3f%:z")))
```

I'm brand new to polars but experienced in pandas. Thanks in advance if this is a simple answer.

Comment: The combination code snippet should work. What is happening exactly? Can you share a runnable example?

Comment: That's pretty strange, the columns I was working with had lots of null values and I was getting errors that made me think it was due to that plus the implicit `strict=True`, but trying it now works as expected. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've written should work:

```py
In [9]: df = pl.DataFrame({
   ...:     'a_at': ['2020-01-01T00:00:00.123+00:00'],
   ...:     'b_at': ['2020-01-02T00:00:00.123+00:00'],
   ...:     'c': [42],
   ...: })

In [10]: df.with_columns(
    ...:     cs.ends_with('_at').str.to_datetime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%.3f%:z").name.suffix('parsed')
    ...: )
Out[10]:
shape: (1, 5)
┌───────────────────────────┬──────────────────────────┬─────┬──────────────────────────┬──────────────────────────┐
│ a_at                      ┆ b_at                     ┆ c   ┆ a_atparsed               ┆ b_atparsed               │
│ ---                       ┆ ---                      ┆ --- ┆ ---                      ┆ ---                      │
│ str                       ┆ str                      ┆ i64 ┆ datetime[ms, UTC]        ┆ datetime[ms, UTC]        │
╞═══════════════════════════╪══════════════════════════╪═════╪══════════════════════════╪══════════════════════════╡
│ 2020-01-01T00:00:00.123+0 ┆ 2020-01-02T00:00:00.123+ ┆ 42  ┆ 2020-01-01 00:00:00.123  ┆ 2020-01-02 00:00:00.123  │
│ 0:00                      ┆ 00:00                    ┆     ┆ UTC                      ┆ UTC                      │
└───────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────┴─────┴──────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────┘
```